# Below is my ajax call where i have called, all code is correct but web service is not getting called.please help me out

Tags: javascript, ajax

platform asp.net with c# :In below function i'm calling my web service. web service is correct but still it is not getting call. please help me out.

```
function saveData() {
var date= new Date().toString();
var testName=document.getElementById('txtName').value;
$.ajax({
        type:"Post",
        url:"http://localhost:1455/WebService1.asmx/saveData",
        data: "{SName:'" + testName + "',data:'"+JSON.stringify(dataOject)+ "',createdOn:'" + date + "'}",
        dataType:"json",
        async:"true",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function(json) {
        alert('data saved');
        },
        error:function(){
        alert('Error occured at server!');
        }
});
```

Comment: Can you check if saveData() is getting called or are there any console log errors? and what is dataOject? Better add whole code including how you are invoking it

Comment: How do you know it isn't called? Does the console of your browser show an error? Does the network tab of the debugger of your browser show the call?

Comment: Yes, In console it shows 500 server error! Which i never got what is it exactly!!!!

Comment: Well, then it's primarily a server-side problem. You'll need to debug the server-side script and find out what is creating the error.